# Nopcommerce long url

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor, fckeditor, nopcommerce

I'm using an old nopcommerce 1.90
When i'm trying to access admin panel it generates very long url in all admin pages...

For example: www.mynopcommercestore.com/(F(rdJxygsKRvgH2-aXCIZR0C3pi39UpnKohhHrrbT1ATunvMt4FfV88V0ebEUgb_XXiUkww8KnBeaG66D6wjA82Kl4UsbeUHmBQN2Pp0fn08yISQ6wyjuFhPZFC-5AiXJuTPvTdDEgf7wCucjqc6hPhK_d-GuuNrpSQklM7tjy4kybCjFA4i15IEGfu8tNUWOV9lCqJBEJuE0CXV96XVhHY2n-ykKlQUxLkoVC49txwzls2iMU0))/administration/ProductDetails.aspx?ProductId=563

What is this "strange" string? cookieless? (i have already set it to false)
I'm getting an error when i'm trying to upload an image in ckeditor

(The server didn't reply with a proper XML data. Please check your configuration.)
XML request error: Request-Uri Too Long (I have also set in web.config maxUrlLength="2097151")

But when i remove this "strange" string from url it uploads well.

Could someone help? How to avoid this long url in system?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2):

You should disable "Cookieless Sessions" in web.config file. Please find more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx)